# JQuery adding and saving data input in row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rows

[image]

I am having trouble saving the new row. When i click on add person I am able to input the data, however, i am not sure how to save it and add a new row.

I know i have to make a function for the save button to work however i am stuck on how to make it work. I have tried a few times but to no avail.

```
var isNewLineToggled = false;
var isAscending = {
    name : false,
    lastName: false,
    dob: false
};
$(".main").append("<input placeholder='search by name' class='search'/><br/><br/>")
$(".main").append("<button onclick=addPerson()>add a person</button><br/><br/>")
var table = $(".main").append("<table></table>");
var thead = '<thead><tr></tr></thead>';
table.append(thead);
var header = [
    { title: 'Name', sortBy: 'name'},
    { title: 'Last Name', sortBy: 'lastName'},
  { title: 'Date of birth', sortBy: 'dob'}
].map(
    function(header) {
     var sortButton = '<button id="' + header.sortBy + '" onclick=sortRows("'+ header.sortBy + '")>/\\</button>';
        $('thead').append('<th>' + header.title + ' ' + sortButton + '</th>');
    }
)
var tbody = "<tbody></tbody>";
var data = [ {name: 'Peter', lastName: 'Petterson', dob: '13/12/1988'},
    {name: 'Anna', lastName: 'Jones', dob: '06/02/1968'},
    {name: 'John', lastName: 'Milton', dob: '01/06/2000'},
    {name: 'James', lastName: 'White', dob: '30/11/1970'},
    {name: 'Luke', lastName: 'Brown', dob: '15/08/1999'}
];
$('.search').change(function(event) {
    searchedName = event.target.value;
})
table.append(tbody);
data.map(
    function(row, i) {
         $('tbody').append(
             '<tr><td>' + row.name +
             '</td><td>' + row.lastName +
             '</td><td>' + row.dob +
             '</td><td><button onclick=editRow('+i+')>edit</button><button>delete</button></td></tr>'
         )
    }
)
 var editableRow = "<td><input/></td><td><input/></td><td><input type='date'/></td><td><button onclick=saveRow()>save</button></td>";

var addPerson = function() {
    isNewLineToggled = !isNewLineToggled;
    if (isNewLineToggled) {
        $('tbody').prepend('<tr>' + editableRow + '</tr>')
  } else {
        $('tbody > tr:first-child').remove();
    }
}

var editRow = function(rowNumber) {
    var name = $('tbody > tr:nth-child('+(rowNumber + 1)+') >      td:first-child').text();
    var lastName = $('tbody > tr:nth-child('+(rowNumber + 1)+') > td:nth-child(2)').text();
    var dob = $('tbody > tr:nth-child('+(rowNumber + 1)+') >     td:nth-child(3)').text();
    $('tbody > tr:nth-child('+(rowNumber + 1)+')').html(editableRow2);
     $('tbody > tr:nth-child('+(rowNumber + 1)+') > td:first-child > input').val(name);
    $('tbody > tr:nth-child('+(rowNumber + 1)+') > td:nth-child(2) > input').val(lastName); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add row like this, two small changes:

`$(".main").append("<button class='add'>add a person</button><br/><br/>")`

Remove inline event handler, no need for it. And your function could be:

```
$('body').on('click','.add', function() { //you will need event delegation, because of dynamically added elements
                isNewLineToggled = !isNewLineToggled;

                if (isNewLineToggled) {
                    $('tbody').prepend('<tr>' + editableRow + '</tr>')
              } else {
                    $('tbody > tr:first-child').remove();
                }
                });
```

Since your editableRow variable isn't defined, i've used just one cell with text for demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/2c97auey/1/

P.S. Your editableRow should have input(s) values, properly placed in cells. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I have a 'save button' that is intended to print another row with the data that was inputted by adding another person. How do i use that event handler to do that? I have edited my code to show this

Comment: @EyedFox1, similar logic...https://jsfiddle.net/q7Lgonhf/ however, you have to add validation of fields, to prevent duplication, etc, etc... but, this is basic idea.

Comment: Thank you @sinisake

Comment: I have another issue. When i click on edit. I would like the date of birth of the person to be shown instead of showing the format. Also the save button doesnt work again. Sorry for this, its just im new to jquery

Comment: Console.log all your vars, debug your code, and check values you get. As i can see, edit and delete buttons doesn't work at all? If this is for some job, i really suggest using of some plugin (this is not so hard to code from scratch, but it is time-consuming job, for sure), if purpose is to learn - try what i described above... :)

Comment: Ah, i see... jsfiddle problem with inline event handlers and jQuery.... will check it, if/when i find the time. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate the help

Comment: Well... this is (sort of) how i would do it: https://jsfiddle.net/e2opd1me/ i've removed all inline event handlers (onclick=something), and i've used classes for targetting, no need for dynamic counting, with jQuery is extremely easy to traverse through dom, your editRow function could be removed now, all buttons are working...code probably could be minified/simplified...If you stack somewhere, open new question, and someone from here will help, i am sure....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e2opd1me/2/ - final, i've just remembered that you need to keep row in the same place after editing...

Comment: This has helped me a lot @ sinisake